# Error al llenar JTextField con datos de JTable

Tags: java

Tengo el problema de que mi programa, me devuelve un error, que no se porqué se produce, a la hora de recoger los datos de una fila de un `JTable` seleccionada y pasarlos a una serie de `JTextField`, el error producido es este:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Adjunto código donde cargo los datos en los textField

```
private void btModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        int rowIndex = tabla.getSelectedRow();
        dni = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex,0));
        nombre = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex,1));
        ciudad = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex,2));


        tfDni.setText(dni);
        tfNombre.setText(nombre);
        tfCiudad.setText(ciudad);

        btInsertar.setEnabled(false);
        btBorrar.setEnabled(false);
        btListado.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

Aquí llamo a la modificación:

```
 private void btAceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        modificar();  
    }
```

Aquí ya si hago la modificación:

```
public void modificar(){
       int rowIndex = tabla.getSelectedRow();

       try{      
       String dni = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex, 0));
       String nombre = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1));
       String ciudad = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex, 2));
       String sql = "update clientes set nombre='"+nombre+"',ciudad='"+ciudad+"' where dni='"+dni+"'";
       /*PARA HACER QUE EL UPDATE COJA LOS VALORES DEL CAMPO DE TEXTO, HABRÍA QUE PASARLE EL tf.getText() que corresponda*/
       mysql.ejecutar(sql);
       }catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Modificar");
       }
    }
```

El constructor de la aplicación es así, creo que el fallo puede estar ahí.

```
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    MySQL mysql;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    Statement st;
    DefaultTableModel modelo;
    String dni;
    String nombre;
    String ciudad;
    ResultSet rs;

public Ventana(MySQL mysql) throws SQLException {
    /*INSTANCIAMOS MYSQL*/
    this.mysql = new MySQL();
    initComponents();
    this.setVisible(true);
    con = mysql.MySQLConnection("pedidos", "root", "1234");
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    tabla.setModel(modelo);

}
```

---

[image: Te adjunto la foto donde capturo las columnas]

Aquí está la foto para que veas todo

---

Aquí te adjunto otra foto que se ve todo el código[image: método resumen]

---

por último te adjunto el método donde muestro lo que hay en la base de datos y saco los metadatos de las columnas[image: metodo listar]

---

[image: Al elegir la fila me devuelve eso]

al elegir la fila me devuelve eso

---

[image: Este es el resultado tras modificar el indice del update]

me devuelve -1, eso quiere decir, a mi entender, que no lo ha actualizado, y efectivamente es así.

---

[image: Esta foto sería mi botón modificar]

[image: Esta sería el método de modificar]

perdón por la tardanza en responder

Comment: Identifica la línea de tu código de donde salta la excepción (estará en el stacktrace). En todo caso, el error es que estas intentando acceder al ítem `0` de un array de longitud `0` (sin elementos). Adicionalmente, en tu código no contemplas la posibilidad de que se pulse el botón sin que haya ninguna fila seleccionada (`getSelectedRow()` devuelve `-1`).

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega el código, así ayudas a ayudarte :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle sería que se quiere acceder a los datos sin haber seleccionado ninguna fila específica del jTable, para evitar este error basta con añadir una condicionante if antes de la ejecución:

//Código de ejemplo

```
private void btModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

if (tabla.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
    int rowIndex = tabla.getSelectedRow();
    dni = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex,0));
    nombre = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex,1));
    ciudad = String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex,2));


    tfDni.setText(dni);
    tfNombre.setText(nombre);
    tfCiudad.setText(ciudad);

    btInsertar.setEnabled(false);
    btBorrar.setEnabled(false);
    btListado.setEnabled(false);
}

}
```

Obs: Una añadidura al código seria poner un aviso al usuario de que no puede modificar el dato si es que no tiene seleccionado ningún registro, o directamente mantener bloqueado el botón hasta que se seleccione al menos un registro.

Comment: he hecho lo que me dices Cristian y en el campo del DNI me escribe -1...

Comment: Podrías pasar una pantalla de los datos que tenes en tu jTable (foto)?, y la declaración de tus columnas(código fuente)?

Comment: ya he compartido las fotos del código

Comment: Allí publiqué la respuesta: Creo que es la parte final que necesitas en tu código

Comment: ya he solucionado lo que le pasaba a mi JTable. era que no estaba instanciando la tabla, estaba definida pero no estaba instanciada, por eso al elegir la fila "no sabía" de donde

Comment: Excelente, solución!!!

Answer (score 1):

Es por el número de columna de tu dni, recuperaste al principio usando la columna cero (0), pero cuando quieres guardar en la bd estás usando la columna uno (1)

Comment: acabo de modificarlo e insertar la foto del código y la ejecucion

Comment: pasa los campos del modelo que usas para la grilla, hay que ver que tenes en la columna 0 y en la columna 1, normalmente yo guardo en la columna 0 la secuencia del detalle, siendo ésta autoincremental despues del guardado, pero antes siempre tiene el valor -1, ahora para el campo dni (documento de identidad) no corresponde ese nro, si vemos tu modelo para los campos quizás podamos aclarar mas cosas

Comment: que es grilla???

Comment: Seria tu Jtable, he visto que trabajas con modelos --->(tabla.setModel(modelo))

Comment: más abajo está la foto. he hecho un tabla.valueArt(tabla.getSelectedRow(), 0) y devuelve eso...

Comment: Un modelo sería básicamente la declaración de las columnas que tendrá tu Jtable: ejemplo:  private DefaultTableModel modelo= new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[] {
   "Secuencia", "Dni", "Nombre", "Ciudad"});... en el Netbeans esto se puede hacer gráficamente en las propiedades de la tabla, esa parte lo que querría ver

Comment: es que las columnas de las tablas, las obtengo de los metadatos de un resultSet